# Courting Disaster with fakeRAID10 (Dual Boot Win7,Ubuntu14.10)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, raid

Over the past several weeks (!), I have been trying to set up a dual boot with Windows 7 Enterprise and Ubuntu Desktop 14.10.  The motherboard is a [Sabertooth x79](http://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_X79/), and I wanted to install everything on a [RAID10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_1.2B0) array comprising four 2TB HDD.

---

### Background/My Process/Description:

> The x79 supports some kind of RAID, which I initially assumed was hardware-based.  By changing a switch in the BIOS, you can change from AHCI to RAID.  You can then set up a RAID array by pressing `CTRL+I` during boot (<sub><sup>the previous owner of the computer had adjusted overclocking settings in the BIOS, which was preventing this menu appearing; resetting to defaults fixed that.  Also, you need to have the BIOS's RAID option chosen</sup></sub>).
>
> #### Installing Windows 7:
>
> Windows doesn't have drivers for the RAID configuration, so on boot it doesn't find any disks.  Copying the motherboard's drivers onto a USB stick (or using the newer one [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=22502&lang=eng&ProdId=3449)) and letting Windows use these drivers during the install (<sub><sup>you must navigate to the directory directly; Windows doesn't search folders for drivers recursively</sup></sub>) allows Windows recognize the RAID10 array as a single drive and install without incident.
>
> #### Installing Ubuntu Desktop:
>
> Setting up Ubuntu was more of a pain.  Although I could boot from a flash drive image, Ubuntu recognized the array--but not as a single disk: as two RAID1 (I think; might've been RAID0 instead, although this would make less sense) disks with several partitions.  Thus, Ubuntu was recognizing only one level of the recursive RAID.
>
> Some more research indicated that this meant that the RAID was not actually a hardware RAID but one step higher: a fakeRAID, which isn't OS-managed like a software RAID nor managed with (completely) dedicated hardware like a hardware RAID.
>
> After many false starts for how to proceed, I finally found [this stackexchange post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455511/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-and-windows-7-on-fakeraid-installation-error-question-m).  Essentially, you connect to the internet, disable `dmraid`, and install `mdadm` instead.  You then call `mdadm --assemble --scan` to get the system to recognize the fakeRAID as a single drive.  Then, you use `gparted` to partition it.  After several attempts, I got that working, putting a small EXT4 and a swap partition immediately after the two NTFS partitions created by Windows (the larger of which I shrunk).
>
> When it came time to actually *install* Ubuntu, however, the installer outright crashed midway (I looked through the log and it looked GRUB-related).  I tried it again with the same result.
>
> Since the Ubuntu USB evidently doesn't save state, rebooting shows the RAID10 array as separate RAID arrays again (since `mdadm` doesn't exist anymore).  As a last-ditch effort (**and this is the key part**), I then installed Ubuntu onto *one* of the EXT4 partitions.  The install completed successfully.
>
> Now, the system happily boots into Windows or Ubuntu.

---

**However, I believe this is courting disaster.**

**The problem is that I (think I )only installed Ubuntu onto one of the arrays within the RAID10 array.**

- **If it was indeed two RAID1s exposed to the OS, then it seems like I installed Ubuntu onto one half of the stripes *as if they were contiguous*.  Note: the boot *could still be successful* if Ubuntu believes the RAID10 are separate RAID1s immediately after boot.**
- **If it was two RAID0s exposed to the OS (i.e. the controller flipped the view, so it looks like RAID01), then I only installed Ubuntu onto one mirror (so, Ubuntu is *not* really backed up, and in any case if reads happen from the unwritten RAID0, then something nasty will happen).**

---

Before I put any real data on this, I need to know what happened and whether the OSes are set up correctly.  My questions (in increasing priority):

1. Is my analysis correct?  Have I only installed Ubuntu onto half of the fakeRAID array?  Or, does writing to one half of a fakeRAID array cause the hardware to write to the other automatically, even if the OS (in this case a LiveCD) wasn't smart enough to tell it to?
2. If there is indeed a problem, is there a way to fix it (so that the data is written to the other half too)?
3. **Is there some kind of check-for-[fake]RAID-consistency I can run?**